# Multiple table in mysql get same unique IDs

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and I have multiple tables in one database. Variables from this form will be stored in those multiple tables. I want to know how to get same unique ID in multiple tables when I submit my form.

Thank you

Comment: What's the need of storing one form data in multiple tables ?
Why don't you store the data in a single table instead of multiple tables..

Comment: I think he's asking about PK's and FK's.

Comment: Dear @Amir Nikfar.. Can you please give us a clarity, what's your actual requirement..

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Make a query inserting the first variable
2. Retrieve the ID of the inserted row (lets call it firstID)
3. Make another query saving the rest of the variables, inserting also the ID = firstID

Answer (score 0):

Well, The best way that I can think of is you can ask the users who fill the form for a unique ID, something like an email address.

Other than that, if the case is that data is inserted in each and every table of your database for every form that is filled then you need not worry as they all will get the same id, just set the id field of each table to auto increment and initial value 0.